# Write operations are not allowed with spring and hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

when I try to save an object I get write operations are not allowed.
Here is the code.
configuration for transaction manager

```
    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate" >
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
            <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"> 
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean> 

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

### Service Class

```
@Service
public class MemberDetailServiceImpl implements MemberDetailService {

@Autowired
private MemberDetailsDao memberDetailsDao; 

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public String saveExtraInfoMember(MemberActivity activity){
    return memberDetailsDao.saveExtraInfoMember(activity);
        }
```

### Dao

```
@Repository
public class MemberDetailsDaoImpl implements MemberDetailsDao {

@Autowired
HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;


public String saveExtraInfoMember(MemberActivity activity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String result=null; 

    hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(activity);   

    return "";
}
```

Comment: When asking about an exception, **always** post the exact and complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.]

Comment: So, you must have set readOnly=true on the method which started the transaction. If, as you were asked, you had posted the complete stack trace of the exception, we could identify that method.